# Setting up Curb in windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, rubygems, curb, feedzirra

I'm trying to use [feedzirra](https://github.com/pauldix/feedzirra) with Rails 3 On Windows 7, but have been having real issues getting Curl and Curb installed.  I found this question [Install Ruby Curb gem in windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511865/install-ruby-curb-gem-in-windows-xp) which enabled me to get the gem installed successfully, but now when I try and start my rails server I get the following error:

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/curb-0.8.1/lib/curb.rb:1:in `require': 193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.   - C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/curb-0.8.1/lib/curb_core.so (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/curb-0.8.1/lib/curb.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/feedzirra-0.0.24/lib/feedzirra.rb:4:in `require'
    ...
```

the file curb_core.so does exist, but windows doesn't know how to open it and says it's not a valid Win32 application.  Any ideas how I can get this to work? Or does anyone know of any other good RSS readers for rails, that don't use Curb?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ben,

Not sure if you're still looking to use Feedzirra, but to get it to work on my machine (Windows 7), I had to copy both `libcurl.dll` and `libidn-11.dll` into the Ruby `bin` directory.  After that it worked with no problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually ended up parsing the RSS myself, and have now moved off that project so unfortunately can't verify if that fixed the problem, but hopefully it will be albe to help someone else!

Answer (score 2):

Try copying libcurl.dll form your curl installation to ruby /bin directory. Solved the problem for me.

Comment: Appreciate the response, but sadly this did not fix the problem for me, I ended up coding my own very basic RSS reader anyway :-(

Comment: doesn't work for me either. I am a bit stuck at the moment. I need this gem for zipline